# WooCommerce Variations - Show which variation isn't available

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm using Woocommerce Swatches and Colours, and I've found that when you pick a variation that isn't in stock, all you see is:

> Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.

But only one of the options selected isn't available - I want to show why it's not available.

So either put the option in the error message or highlight the swatch that isn't in stock.

Has anyone figured this one out?

Comment: maybe it's a bug, days ago i had a similar problem, i restart and update my theme, because it was giving me some problems with the variations, in case you want something different, why not  check this out? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nedGdx32SjE

Comment: @CarlosCarrizales it's my own theme, so there's nothing I can update as such

Comment: psss, you should try in another one, if that's the case, just to try it